# Seems like 'V1Event' is missing form kubernetes client library for Python and can't be imported anymore

Tags: python, kubernetes

Seems like 'V1Event' is missing form kubernetes client library for Python and can't be imported anymore

In the past it was imported that way:

```
from kubernetes.client import (
    V1ContainerState,
    V1ContainerStateRunning,
    V1ContainerStateTerminated,
    V1ContainerStateWaiting,
    V1ContainerStatus,
    V1Event,
)
```

But now in kubernetes version 26.1.0 it not possible following error is returned

```
home/dev/ .tox/run-tests/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py:325: PluggyTeardownRaisedWarning: A plugin raised an exception during an old-style hookwrapper teardown.

Plugin: helpconfig, Hook: pytest_cmdline_parse

ConftestImportFailure: ImportError: cannot import name 'V1Event' from 'kubernetes' (/home/dev/ .tox/run-tests/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kubernetes/__init__.py) (from /home/dev/ tests/conftest.py)

For more information see https://pluggy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_reference.html#pluggy.PluggyTeardownRaisedWarning

  config = pluginmanager.hook.pytest_cmdline_parse(

ImportError while loading conftest '/home/dev/ tests/conftest.py'.

tests/conftest.py:19: in <module>

    from .mockubernetes_utils import Mocks

tests/mockubernetes_utils.py:19: in <module>

    from kubernetes import  V1Event

E   ImportError: cannot import name 'V1Event' from 'kubernetes' (/home/dev/ .tox/run-tests/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kubernetes/__init__.py)

run-tests: exit 4 (3.43 seconds) /home/dev > pytest --ignore target/ --cov --cov-report=html --cov-report=xml pid=24115
```

I've tried to import it from `kubernetes.client.models` but it is the same

```
import kubernetes.client.models
```

```
ConftestImportFailure: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kubernetes.client.model' (from /home/dev/ tests/conftest.py)
```

For more information see

```
https://pluggy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_reference.html#pluggy.PluggyTeardownRaisedWarning

  config = pluginmanager.hook.pytest_cmdline_parse(

ImportError while loading conftest '/home/dev/ tests/conftest.py'.

tests/conftest.py:19: in <module>

    from .mockubernetes_utils import Mocks

tests/mockubernetes_utils.py:18: in <module>

    from kubernetes.client.model import V1Event

E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kubernetes.client.model'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
from kubernetes.client import ( CoreV1Event, CoreV1EventList)
```

It is changed since version 19

Answer (score 0):

Library is renamed to CoreV1Event import path is the same.